# Using datatable in place of list in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I wrote the following query in LINQ:
`memberlist` is `List` of `membershipuserwrapper`

```
List<usercodes> testlist = new List<usercodes>();
                testlist.Add(new usercodes { usercode = "na02\\srosner" });
                testlist.Add(new usercodes { usercode = "Schie@testtest.com" });

var filtered = (from c in memberList
                where (from t in testlist 
                       select t.usercode.ToLower())
                       .Contains(c.UserName.ToLower())
                select c)
                .ToList();
```

Now, I have `DataTable` with a list of users in place of `testlist` and I want to use that `DataTable` in place of my LINQ query.

Can I use that how to do that in way of `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
from t in testlist.AsEnumerable()
select t.Field<string>("usercode").ToLower()
```

in place of the original:

```
from t in testlist
select t.usercode.ToLower()
```

Personally, though, I'd say that the `List<usercodes>` is a vast improvement from a `DataTable`, and would encourage you to pursue the original version (maybe changing the class-name to `UserCodes` or similar).

Comment: thanks, but I need to prepare list from datatable if I use List<usercode>.

Comment: @Keyur or you need to ask the question: "why am I using a `DataTable` at all?"

Comment: yeah, thanks for your answer. generally am using lists but one of old method returns datatable so asked question on it.